# How to convert string to date and then parse it to correct string output in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, datetime

I get date as string from backend and now at first I need to convert it to date time and then to compare this date and current date difference in years, months, weeks, days, minutes and seconds. In JS I can do this easily with moment JS like this

```
function extractTime(time) {
  return {
    seconds: moment().diff(time, 'seconds'),
    minutes: moment().diff(time, 'minutes'),
    hours: moment().diff(time, 'hours'),
    days: moment().diff(time, 'days'),
    weeks: moment().diff(time, 'weeks'),
    months: moment().diff(time, 'months'),
    years: moment().diff(time, 'years'),
  };
}
```

Is there something similar in Kotlin that I can achieve same result?

Comment: Classes in the java.time package are what you need:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html.   Your can use a formatter to convert a string that matches a pattern like "yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss.SSS" and gives you a LocalDateTime.  You can easily use that to do comparisons and manipulations.

Comment: Thx a lot. How to do actually comparison by week? I can use for hours, minutes, days and seconds Duration but no idea how to get difference in weeks.

Comment: I would not expect it to know weeks.  You'll have to work that out.  Very use case specific, wouldn't you agree?  For example, what day do you want to say is the start of a week?  Sun or Mon?   No surprise that there's no general solution.

Comment: Don't write code manipulating dates or times yourself. Just don't. There's a wealth of ugly corner cases, complications, and downright insanity hiding there — and you don't need to worry about any of it, coz smart (and/or obsessed) people have done all the hard work for you! Just use the `java.time` classes, and sleep easy. See the [obligatory Tom Scott video](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY).

Comment: (In fact, you've already brought up one complication: there are many different ways you could get the number of weeks between two days. Even assuming the Gregorian calendar, and the same time-zone, are you looking for weeks that start on a Sunday? Or a Monday? Or that start on the first provided date, or the earlier date if they're not in order? How should the time of day be taken into account, if the later time is earlier in the day that the earlier one? And what happens if summer time (AKA daylight-saving time) starts or ends in between the two?)